# how to mock failure for google oauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, google-oauth

I am doing integration testing on omniauth. I am following this tutorial.

https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Integration-Testing

The tutorial says in order to mock failure we put this line

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = :invalid_credentials
```

When i use facebook, it works. i.e it throws invalid credentials

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = :invalid_credentials
```

When i use google, it doesn't work. i.e it successfully authenticates

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google] = :invalid_credentials
```

Why does gmail not work? should i use any other symbol other than :google. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Try `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] = :invalid_credentials`

Comment: that did it . please put it in answer and i ll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using [Google Oauth2 Strategy](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2). For that you need to use the key `:google_oauth2` instead of `:google`:

```
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] = :invalid_credentials
```